# Codeigniter 3.x Ajax Pagination

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

Hello (it's my first post) I post because i really need help for paginate the results by category on codeigniter.
When i click on the link generated, the page loads to infinity. This pagination is ok on the index page for all results. But i need paginate by category.
thank you very very much in advance for you're help.

The Controler:

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model(array('Blog_model'));
    $this->load->library('Ajax_pagination');    
    $this->perPage = 3;
}
    function category($category_id)//category page
{
    $data = array();

    //total rows count
    $totalRec = count($this->Blog_model->getRowsByCat($category_id));
    //pagination configuration
    $config['target']      = '#postwrap';
    $config['base_url']    = base_url().'blog/category/'.$category_id.'/ajaxPaginationCat';
    $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
    $config['per_page']    = $this->perPage;

    $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);

    //get the posts data
    $data['posts'] = $this->Blog_model->getRowsByCat($category_id,array('limit'=>$this->perPage));
    //
    $data['main_content'] = "blog/category";
    $this->load->view('template',$data);
}

    function ajaxPaginationCat($category_id){
    $page = $this->input->post('page');
    if(!$page){
        $offset = 0;
    }else{
        $offset = $page;
    }

    //total rows count
    $totalRec = count($this->Blog_model->getRowsByCat($category_id));

    //pagination configuration
    $config['target']      = '#postwrap';
    $config['base_url']    = base_url().'blog/category/'.$category_id.'/ajaxPaginationCat';
    $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
    $config['per_page']    = $this->perPage;

    $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);

    //get posts data
    $data['posts'] = $this->Blog_model->getRowsByCat($category_id,array('start'=>$offset,'limit'=>$this->perPage));

    //load the view
    $this->load->view('blog/ajax-pagination-data', $data, false);
}
```

The Model:

```
 /*
 * get rows from the posts table
 */
function getRowsByCat($category_id,$params = array()){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('blog_posts');
    $this->db->order_by('post_id','desc');

    if(!empty($category_id)){
        $this->db->where('category_id',$category_id);
    }

    //set start and limit
    if(array_key_exists("start",$params) && array_key_exists("limit",$params)){
        $this->db->limit($params['limit'],$params['start']);
    }elseif(!array_key_exists("start",$params) && array_key_exists("limit",$params)){
        $this->db->limit($params['limit']);
    }
    //get records
    $query = $this->db->get();
    //return fetched data
    return ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->result_array():FALSE;
}
```

Library:

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

/**
 * Pagination Class
 *
 * @package   CodeIgniter
 * @link      http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html
 * 
 * Modified by CodexWorld.com
 * @Ajax pagination functionality has added with this library. 
 * @It will helps to integrate Ajax pagination with loading image in CodeIgniter application.
 * @TutorialLink http://www.codexworld.com/ajax-pagination-in-codeigniter-framework/
 */
class Ajax_pagination{

```
var $base_url        = ''; // The page we are linking to
var $total_rows      = ''; // Total number of items (database results)
var $per_page        = 10; // Max number of items you want shown per page
var $num_links       =  2; // Number of "digit" links to show before/after the currently viewed page
var $cur_page        =  0; // The current page being viewed
var $first_link      = 'First';
var $next_link       = '&#187;';
var $prev_link       = '&#171;';
var $last_link       = 'Last';
var $uri_segment     = 3;
var $full_tag_open   = '<div class="pagination">';
var $full_tag_close  = '</div>';
var $first_tag_open  = '';
var $first_tag_close = '&nbsp;';
var $last_tag_open   = '&nbsp;';
var $last_tag_close  = '';
var $cur_tag_open    = '&nbsp;<b>';
var $cur_tag_close   = '</b>';
var $next_tag_open   = '&nbsp;';
var $next_tag_close  = '&nbsp;';
var $prev_tag_open   = '&nbsp;';
var $prev_tag_close  = '';
var $num_tag_open    = '&nbsp;';
var $num_tag_close   = '';
var $target          = '';
var $anchor_class    = '';
var $show_count      = true;
var $link_func       = 'getData';
var $loading         = '.loading';

/**
 * Constructor
 * @access    public
 * @param    array    initialization parameters
 */
function CI_Pagination($params = array()){
    if (count($params) > 0){
        $this->initialize($params);        
    }
    log_message('debug', "Pagination Class Initialized");
}

/**
 * Initialize Preferences
 * @access    public
 * @param    array    initialization parameters
 * @return    void
 */
function initialize($params = array()){
    if (count($params) > 0){
        foreach ($params as $key => $val){
            if (isset($this->$key)){
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
        }        
    }

    // Apply class tag using anchor_class variable, if set.
    if ($this->anchor_class != ''){
        $this->anchor_class = 'class="' . $this->anchor_class . '" ';
    }
}

/**
 * Generate the pagination links
 * @access    public
 * @return    string
 */    
function create_links(){
    // If our item count or per-page total is zero there is no need to continue.
    if ($this->total_rows == 0 OR $this->per_page == 0){
       return '';
    }

    // Calculate the total number of pages
    $num_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

    // Is there only one page? Hm... nothing more to do here then.
    if ($num_pages == 1){
        $info = 'Showing : ' . $this->total_rows;
        return $info;
    }

    // Determine the current page number.        
    $CI =& get_instance();    
    if ($CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) != 0){
        $this->cur_page = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);   
        // Prep the current page - no funny business!
        $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
    }

    $this->num_links = (int)$this->num_links;
    if ($this->num_links < 1){
        show_error('Your number of links must be a positive number.');
    }

    if ( ! is_numeric($this->cur_page)){
        $this->cur_page = 0;
    }

    // Is the page number beyond the result range?
    // If so we show the last page
    if ($this->cur_page > $this->total_rows){
        $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1) * $this->per_page;
    }

    $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;
    $this->cur_page = floor(($this->cur_page/$this->per_page) + 1);

    // Calculate the start and end numbers. These determine
    // which number to start and end the digit links with
    $start = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
    $end   = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

    // Add a trailing slash to the base URL if needed
    $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';

    // And here we go...
    $output = '';

    // SHOWING LINKS
    if ($this->show_count){
        $curr_offset = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);
        $info = 'Showing ' . ( $curr_offset + 1 ) . ' to ' ;

        if( ( $curr_offset + $this->per_page ) < ( $this->total_rows -1 ) )
        $info .= $curr_offset + $this->per_page;
        else
        $info .= $this->total_rows;

        $info .= ' of ' . $this->total_rows . ' | ';
        $output .= $info;
    }

    // Render the "First" link
    if  ($this->cur_page > $this->num_links){
        $output .= $this->first_tag_open 
                . $this->getAJAXlink( '' , $this->first_link)
                . $this->first_tag_close;
    }

    // Render the "previous" link
    if  ($this->cur_page != 1){
        $i = $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;
        if ($i == 0) $i = '';
        $output .= $this->prev_tag_open 
                . $this->getAJAXlink( $i, $this->prev_link )
                . $this->prev_tag_close;
    }

    // Write the digit links
    for ($loop = $start -1; $loop <= $end; $loop++){
        $i = ($loop * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;    
        if ($i >= 0){
            if ($this->cur_page == $loop){
                $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$loop.$this->cur_tag_close; // Current page
            }else{
                $n = ($i == 0) ? '' : $i;
                $output .= $this->num_tag_open
                    . $this->getAJAXlink( $n, $loop )
                    . $this->num_tag_close;
            }
        }
    }

    // Render the "next" link
    if ($this->cur_page < $num_pages){
        $output .= $this->next_tag_open 
            . $this->getAJAXlink( $this->cur_page * $this->per_page , $this->next_link )
            . $this->next_tag_close;
    }

    // Render the "Last" link
    if (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages){
        $i = (($num_pages * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page);
        $output .= $this->last_tag_open . $this->getAJAXlink( $i, $this->last_link ) . $this->last_tag_close;
    }

    // Kill double slashes.  Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash
    // in the penultimate link so we'll kill all double slashes.
    $output = preg_replace("#([^:])//+#", "\\1/", $output);

    // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
    $output = $this->full_tag_open.$output.$this->full_tag_close;
    ?>
    <script>
    function getData(page){  
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $this->base_url; ?>"+page,
            data: { page: page },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('<?php echo $this->loading; ?>').show();
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('<?php echo $this->loading; ?>').hide();
                $('<?php echo $this->target; ?>').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    <?php
    return $output;
}

function getAJAXlink($count, $text) {
    $pageCount = $count?$count:0;
    return '<a href="javascript:void(0);"' . $this->anchor_class . ' onclick="'.$this->link_func.'('.$pageCount.')">'. $text .'</a>';
}
```

}
// END Pagination Class

And the Ajax generated:

```
                    <script>
    function getData(page){  
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "blog/category/1/ajaxPaginationCat/"+page,
            data: { page: page },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.loading').show();
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('.loading').hide();
                $('#postwrap').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

thank you so much!

Comment: you are going to have to be a lot more specific, and include some of your own troubleshooting paths and what that has yielded in terms of understanding the problem. further as your issue involves js, it should be included. again, more specific, more verifiable.

Comment: Hello, thank a lot. I solved the problem by changing the $data conditions.